# JS - Show a div only when a number is typed

Tags: javascript

I have a form with an `input type="number"`, and I need to display a div if the user types a number within a range.

My current code only works when I reload the page, but I want to display the `"#alert-one"` div when the numeric range is typed (not when the page reloads).

What am I doing wrong...?

Thanks in advance!

---

**CSS:**

```
#alert-one {
    display:none
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="alert-one">Hello</div>

<input type="number" id="enviara" name="enviara" maxlength="5" required>
```

**Script:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function alertaislas() {
    const total = Number($("#enviara").val().replace(".",""));

    if(total > 28999 && total < 29999) {
      $('#alert-one').show();
    }

    else{
      $('#alert-one').hide();
}}

    alertaislas();
});
```

Comment: Attach your function to the `input` event of the input. You only call it upon the while document being reloaded.

Comment: @WiktorZychla I'm a newbie at JS. I still don't know how to do what you say. Can you give me an example? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute the function on `input` event of the element like the following way:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  alertaislas();
});

$(document).on('input','#enviara',alertaislas);

function alertaislas() {
  const total = Number($("#enviara").val().replace(".",""));
  if(total > 28999 && total < 29999) {
    $('#alert-one').show();
  }
  else{
    $('#alert-one').hide();
  }
}
```

```css
#alert-one {
   display:none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="alert-one">Hello</div>

<input type="number" id="enviara" name="enviara" maxlength="5" required>
```

Comment: Bravo! ... Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

You only have to make two little changes to your js code.

The first is, that you have to call `alertaislas` on change of the input and you have to change the `show` and `hide` method, to `css("display","block")` and `css("display","none")`

Here is the corrected code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function alertaislas() {
    const total = Number($("#enviara").val().replace(".",""));

    if(total > 28999 && total < 29999) {
      $('#alert-one').css("display", "block");
    }

    else{
      $('#alert-one').css("display", "none");
}}

    $("#enviara").change(alertaislas);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually this won't display anything without reloading.
You must use jquery inline html `onkeyup=myfn()` as well as `onchange=myfn()`

as follows:

HTML :

```
<div id="alert-one">Hello</div>

<input type="number" id="enviara" name="enviara" maxlength="5" onkeyup="alertaislas()" onchange="alertaislas()" required>
```

Javascript/Jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function alertaislas() {
    const total = Number($("#enviara").val().replace(".",""));

    if(total > 28999 && total < 29999) {
      $('#alert-one').show();
    }

    else{
      $('#alert-one').hide();
}}


});
```

Comment: The `onkeyup` will possibly not be triggered in all scenarios (like pasting). `input` should work always.

Comment: @Tarekas I made the changes, but it doesn't work for me. It only works when I reload the page, not when I type the number

Comment: @Pablo_Web please check that jquery library is referenced in your HTML 

put this at the end of your body of your html 

```<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>```